# How to checkout old version of folder in git

Tags: git

I need to pull changes from origin. Problem is that one of libs was updated to newest version and it crashes my part of application. I would like to pull recent changes and then go back to previous (or specific) version for only one folder, which contains that problem causing lib. Is there any way to do that?

Comment: In case anyone is wondering how to view the old file without overwriting the current version, this might be useful: `git show 19bf5f6:someFile.java`

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
git checkout LAST_WORKING_COMMIT -- vendor/library/in/question
```

This will check out the folder in the version of `LAST_WORKING_COMMIT`. However, `git status` will then tell, that the files are modified:

```
$ git status
# On branch master
# Changes not staged for commit:
#   (use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
#   (use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)
#
#       modified:   vendor/library/in/question/file.exe
#
no changes added to commit (use "git add" and/or "git commit -a")
```

Comment: That was exactly what i needed. Thanks. Is there any way to have those changed files not added to index automatically?

Comment: `git update-index --assume-unchanged vendor/library/in/question` does that. Not a very intuitive command :-(. To reverse: `git update-index --no-assume-unchanged vendor/library/in/question`

Comment: Works nice for modified files but it seems that files that were added after `LAST_WORKING_COMMIT` will not be removed.

Comment: Yes (and that's most of the time the decent thing to do for git), but you can prefix the command with a `rm -fr vendor/library/in/question` to get that result.

Answer (score 7):

Use an additional argument to `git checkout`:

```
git checkout REV -- folder
```